# Is there a way to quickly identify all matching coding region sequences based on a list of protein identifiers from all GTDB representatives?

Tags: linux, database, bioinformatics, protein-database

I need to find the matching coding region sequences (CDS) of a custom made "Hit list" of protein names (just a textfile of names) from the GTDB representatives (which can be downloaded from the GTDB webpage => https://data.gtdb.ecogenomic.org/releases/latest/genomic_files_reps).

As a side note, I cannot use the hit list to just fetch the CDS for the respective proteins on GTDB/NCBI, as the "protein names" of the GTDB representative files are actually just the NCBI genome accession number with a natural number assigned to each protein from this genome (e.g. AE017199.1_1, AE017199.1_2, AE017199.1_3 etc.).

So far, I have created a bash script which allows me to identify the protein names within the header of all fna entries within a genome, which contain one of the protein names from the hit list and then collect these sequences entries. Unfortunately, for the bacterial fna files containing the CDS of all GDTB representatives, it would amount to a total of about 6 months to finish the script.

This is a snippet of the script I have used (the textfile of proteinnames was changed into an array in prior):

```
for gz_file in "$zip_directory"/*.fna.gz; do
    current_file=$((current_file + 1))
    echo "Processing file $current_file of $total_files"
    gzip -dc "$gz_file" | while IFS= read -r line; do
        if [[ $line == ">"* ]]; then
            for word in "${words[@]}"; do
                if [[ $line == *"$word "* ]]; then
                    echo "$line - $(basename "$gz_file" .fna.gz)" >> "$temp_dir/$(basename "$gz_file" .fna.gz).temp"
                    while IFS= read -r next_line && [[ ! $next_line == ">"* ]]; do
                        echo "$next_line" >> "$temp_dir/$(basename "$gz_file" .fna.gz).temp"
                    done
                    break
                fi
            done
        fi
    done
done
```

Thus, I asked myself, whether there is a more convenient way to collect the corresponding GTDB-reps CDS for the Hit list, for instance by running all files in parallel or a more convenient approach in general.

I would be deeply appreciative of any help and suggestions for this kind of issue.

Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: Please provide some [simplified] sample data and the expected result. No images or external links, please.

Comment: How big is 'a custom made "Hit list" of protein names (just a textfile of names)', and what's the format? What's your expected output from the files referenced in the link?

Comment: Hit lists can contain >1000 proteinnames. Theyre just text files in which protein names are newline separated. Two example protein names: WUQU03124324.1_7 AEQU01120179.1_2 The files which I then want to find the matching CDS in, are all CDS from all representatives stored as individual gzipped fna-files. All of them have the same structure: >WUQU03124324.1_7 ...(residual header info)
ATGCGAA...(rest of sequence)
>AEQU01120179.1_2 ...(residual header info)
ATGAAA...(rest of sequence)
I just want to find the headers containing right proteinnames & pool output over all matched sequences.

Comment: Results should just be header and their sequences which matched any of the hit list proteinnames. Same format as the files from the link (=fasta format)

Comment: You should add the information in your comments to the question post, where it can be formatted properly.

Comment: You say the _"Hit list"_ is _a textfile_, but in the _snippet of the script_ you have an array `words`; you should clarify that.

Comment: @Armali
The textfile was processed into an array of "words" prior to this snippet. But the general idea is the same and it starts with the textfile. If you have better suggestions please let me know, as I am not an expert on coding.

Comment: The script has a bug - since it reads the _rest of sequence_ until a line with `>`, that line is consumed and not taken into comparison with `words`, i. e. a match immediately following a match is lost. - Is there really anywhere after the _residual header info_ more than one line of _rest of sequence_?

Comment: @Armali
Thank you very much for pointing this out! This explains the sometimes missing couple of sequences that I have to add manually afterwards. Yes, unfortunately the "rest of sequence" is not just one line and includes multiple lines following thereafter.

Comment: I have to reconfirm - even though the "rest of sequence" occupies multiple screen lines, in the one file I inspected (ar53_ssu_reps_r214.fna) it's always on a single logical line. Can you point me to a file with multiple logical "rest of sequence" lines?

Comment: e.g. this one (shortened): But maybe I also understand something incorrectly and this is in fact one line following the header:
>lcl|SOKP01000057.1_cds_TET02564.1_524 [locus_tag=E3J90_02505] [protein=hypothetical protein] [protein_id=TET02564.1] [location=717..2036] [gbkey=CDS] - GCA_004375715.1
ATGGATGGAGGGGTAATTAAGATGAATGCAGAACAACTTGTTAAGGAAAGAGTTCAGAGAGTGAGAGATGCAGTTGCGTT
AAAAGAACCTGATCGCGTTCCGATTACTCCTTTTACTGATATTTTTTTTGCTCCCCTCCAGGTGGGAATGACGCATAAGG
AAGCGATGTACAAAGGTAGAAAATATACTAAAGCTGCTGTTAAAGTTTATAGTCGGTATAATTGGGATCTTTATCCAACC

Answer (score 0):

We can gain some speed by replacing the inner loops with a `sed` command.

```
IFS=\|
regexp="${words[*]//|/\\|}"
for gz_file in "$zip_directory"/*.fna.gz
do  current_file=$((current_file + 1))
    echo "Processing file $current_file of $total_files"
    file=$(basename "$gz_file" .fna.gz)
    gzip -dc "$gz_file" |
    sed -nr "/$regexp/{s/$/ - $file/;:0;p;n;/^>/!b0;s/^/\n/;D}" >"$temp_dir/$file.temp"
done
```

But it seems advisable to use a DBMS rather than plain text files for such big data processing.